# Using content_tag to underline part of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-tag

Currently I am using content_tag in my controller helper to reduce a lot of the logic that was being performed in the view. I understand getting nested content_tags to work but the one thing that keeps hanging me up is if I had the following

```
<div id="content"><u>Click here</u> to unlock</div>
```

then how could i do this using content_tag or is there a better way?

Comment: If it's just static HTML, there's not really a reason to move the code from the view. If you reuse it, put it in a partial. Helpers are good for some sort of dynamic output.

Comment: the code above is just a small snippet there is a not more to the helper that is dynamic

Comment: If you're interested in simplifying your views then it can be the time to start learning slim: http://slim-lang.com/.

Comment: @jdoe ha! I work with the creator of slim. Pretty good stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
content_tag(:div, content_tag(:u, 'Click here') + ' to unlock', id: 'content')
```